# After upgrade to ubuntu 12.04.1 the screen is black

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit to 12.04.1. When I restart the laptop and select Ubuntu (I have Windows 7 also); the screen becomes black. I enter the password and login to  Ubuntu and I still don't see anything .

My notebook is Acer 5736Z. processor: dual core Pentium T4500. Graphics card: Intel Express (GMA 4500M). 3GB RAM

Thank you for help

Comment: Please see possible duplicate question: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

After the computer is turned on, please press

```
Alt+Ctrl+F1
```

and log in.

(If you succeded) generate the Xorg file:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

Restart your computer. If this didn't help, please paste the generated file content.

Regards

Comment: Do u mean I press Alt+Ctrl+F1 before logging to Ububtu? I tried it but didn't help (nothing..)

Comment: Best regards :)

Comment: ok, so try to press shift (as many times as possible) while booting to enter the GRUB. then select recovery mode or text mode and see if then you will be able to do it.